# Regex to find date change in log file

Tags: regex, date, compare, width, fixed

My log file is in the following format

```
mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss     Description

11/05/2013 03:01:00     Shutting down server...

11/05/2013 03:01:23     DumpCache(): 284114 items.
```

To keep things simple I can use the following regex to match the date

```
^(../../....)
```

This works because I know every line starts with a 10 digit date including slashes. But the purpose of this search is not to find every line in the log, it is to find when the next line does not match the previous line (date change).

I imagine that a look behind is capable of doing this, but I cannot figure out how to ignore the description and the time and only look at the date of the previous line.

Comment: IN which language/script you want this?

Comment: So in this case, you would want to match only the 1st line since the 2nd line does not match?

Comment: I want to do this in notepad++, I was just using the find/replace dialog which allows for some regex, but I think that is too limited.  I just found that there is a python plugin for it, that works, but if there is a native scripting language for notepad++ that would be preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python:

```
import re

diff_line_re = re.compile(r'''
(?:
        (?P<date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})
              \s+
        (?P<time>[\d:]+)
              \s+
        (?P<message>[^\n]+)
              \n
)(?!(?P=date))
''', re.X)
```

Given the data:

```
log_lines = '''
11/05/2013 03:01:00     1 Shutting down server...
11/05/2013 03:01:23     2 DumpCache(): 284114 items.
11/05/2013 03:01:00     3 Shutting down server...
11/07/2013 03:01:23     5 DumpCache(): 284114 items.
11/07/2013 03:01:00     6 Shutting down server...
11/08/2013 03:01:23     7 DumpCache(): 284114 items.
11/08/2013 03:01:00     8 Shutting down server...
11/09/2013 03:01:23     9 DumpCache(): 284114 items.
'''
```

We execute the script:

```
print(diff_line_re.findall(log_lines))
```

Ouput:

```
[('11/05/2013', '03:01:00', '3 Shutting down server...'), 
 ('11/07/2013', '03:01:00', '6 Shutting down server...'), 
 ('11/08/2013', '03:01:00', '8 Shutting down server...'), 
 ('11/09/2013', '03:01:23', '9 DumpCache(): 284114 items.')]
```

See python regexes documentation for details: http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re

Comment: Thanks for the response.  What if I wanted to return the first 2 lines with the same date, or the first 5 lines?

Comment: That would be much easier to do without regexps.  I.e. you can still use a regexp to parse one line, but after that, just iterate through parsed lines and implement whatever logic you need.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, I would mark your answer as useful if I could.